# Bar plot based on list of string values

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm doing some clustering which results in a list of strings like this:

```
['5-3-2', '5-3-2', '4-3-2-1', ...]
```

I want to plot a bar chart based on the frequency of the strings. Is there an easy way to do this? I think I could identify the unique elements in the list and count them, but maybe there is a more comfortable solution?

EDIT: Further information

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    import math as math
    import Utils as ut
    from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
    from itertools import cycle

...
    result = np.array(result)
    keys, counts = np.unique(result, return_counts=True)
    print('Keys: ', keys)
    print('Counts: ', counts)

    print(result)

    plt.bar(keys,counts)
    plt.show
```

Output:

```
Keys:  ['3-1-4-2' '3-2-3-2' '3-3-2-2' '4-2-2-2' '4-2-3-1' '4-4-2']
Counts:  [ 21 154  23   1  48   4]
```

EDIT 2: plot shows in debug mode with breakpoint on `plt.show`, when I step over it disappears. So its not visible in run mode. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your expected output from this data?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) can return the counts of the unique elements of a list.

```
keys, counts = np.unique(x, return_counts=True)
```

You may then plot those as bar plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = ['5-3-2', '5-3-2', '4-3-2', "2-3-2", '4-3-2', '4-3-2', "1-2-4"]
keys, counts = np.unique(x, return_counts=True)

plt.bar(keys, counts)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! There doesn't seem to be any output from this code: no error, no chart. I'll edit further information.

Comment: If there is no output figure from a matplotlib code upon `plt.show` the issue is with your way of using the python interpreter. This has nothing to do with how to create a histogram.

Answer (score 1):

A bar plot of frequencies is essentially a histogram. Luckily, `matplotlib.pyplot` has built in histogram methods!

Assuming your list is called `x`, you can just do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# the bins argument says how many bars (set to the number of unique values in your list)
# the rwidth argument is there so that the bars are not squished together
plt.hist(x, bins=len(set(x)), rwidth = 0.8)
plt.show()
```

This gives you a histogram of the frequency of the items in your list

Comment: The result of this is general not very nice, because bars are misaligned to the labels. In any case, you need to specify the number of bars, otherwise the plot will be nonsense.

Comment: Your way is better (more aesthetic for sure); I leave mine up (with an edit to take into account the number of bars) just in case it ends up being useful to someone.